# Debian 10: How can I change the screen resolution for remote desktop with xrdp and remmina

Tags: debian, remote-desktop, remmina

I have two Debian 10 systems, and I am trying to remote manage one from the other.

I am using remmina as the client and xrdp as the server. I connect with RDP protocol.

How can I change the screen resolution. It is currently stuck with display rdp0 smaller than 640x480.

Is this a client or server side setting?

Comment: it's a server side setting  `-geometry 1025x768` or something like that I think

Comment: @Jasen Interestingly having posted this question, I tried connecting with the Windows 10 RDP client, and found I was able to set the resolution in the settings client side. Any idea why this might have been the case. Despite being on my home network it's also super lagy.

Comment: maybe they changed it since last time  i looked.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Solution

This was another issue caused by a program which has a criminally bad UI. I've figured it out now. It's a client side setting.

- Click the button on the top window decoration which contains an icon with 3 lines on it.
- Select preferences. Why preferences are hidden in this menu with an obscure button with an obscure icon I have no clue. (First bad UI design problem)
- On the default "Options" tab (second bad UI design element, bad generic name "Options" when all the tabs are different types of options
- Click button "Set up" next to the text "Screen Resolutions" (third bad element of UI design. Easy to miss text. Not obvious that button is related to "Screen Resolutions" by looking at it.
- Add 1920x1080 or whatever you want. Be careful of syntax. Must be NxM format.
- Close this window
- On main Remmina window, now click top left button which is a page symbol with a plus on it. This is to add a new profile. (Again bad UI design)
- Put server address in and change Resolution to "Custom" (select one). Test before changing other options

Remmina dev team please fix the UI!

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Almost a year later and still the same crappy ux.

Comment: If this answer becomes obsolete please add a comment letting me know. The fact it is still receiving upvotes tells me this is still relevant information.

Comment: This...this is the kind of poor design that drives people to use Windows. Thank you.

Comment: @nerdfever.com Blame Gnome 3. It's a Gnome 3 thing not a Linux thing. All Gnome 3 apps suck.

Comment: @user3728501 Can you suggest a better one (not Gnome 3)? FWIW, once you figure out the (horrible) UI, it works quite well.

Comment: @nerdfever.com I don't know any alternatives to Remmina, but if you want an actual useable desktop environment use xfce or mate. Alternatively, try KDE, but again I'm not a fan of it and seemingly the gtk based desktops are more popular than the QT ones these days. I haven't heard of anyone using KDE for ages